# I am looking for a way to push mac software from AD server to connected MAC clients

Tags: macos, active-directory

We have an AD server to which windows and Mac clients are registered. We are able to push msi package to all connected Windows clients through a GPO policy. We are trying to push Mac package to Mac clients. Can anyone suggest any idea or documents to create GPO for mac clients. Any information is very much appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an third party product it's possible: ADmitMac or PowerBroker Identity Services Open

On a normal mac there is no software that could evaluate a group policy